# Missing trait items: `__ink_TraitInfo`, `pausedOutput`

Tags: ink, openbrush

I copied the [pausable ink example](https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts/tree/main/examples/pausable) and am running into the following error (here is the [repo](https://github.com/ok-Alice/liquid-staking/tree/main/contracts/staker)/`diamond-pattern` branch):

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `__ink_TraitInfo`, `pausedOutput`
 --> /home/snowmead/opt/projects/liquid-staking/contracts/staker_facet_v1/src/lib.rs:4:1
  |
4 | #[openbrush::contract]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `__ink_TraitInfo`, `pausedOutput` in implementation
  |
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `openbrush::contract` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  = help: implement the missing item: `type __ink_TraitInfo = /* Type */;`
  = help: implement the missing item: `type pausedOutput = /* Type */;`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0046`.
error: could not compile `staker_facet_v1` (lib) due to previous error
```

Comment: https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts/issues/33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was missing `#[ink(message)]` on the `paused` implemented method.After adding this solved my problem.